# how to solve this definite integration?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I have this integration which I am not able to solve:

$$I=\int_{M}^{\infty} \left(x^n \exp\left(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\right)\right) dx$$
where, $m_s, B,n,K$ are constant and $n > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\frac{d}{dx}\exp \Big( \frac{-m_s}{Bx+K} \Big)=\frac{m_sB\exp \Big( \frac{-m_s}{Bx+K} \Big)}{(Bx+K)^2}$. For $x\in (-K/B, \infty)$, $\frac{d}{dx}\exp \Big( \frac{-m_s}{Bx+K} \Big)$ is defined, and not equal to $0$. Furthermore, $\exp \Big( \frac{-m_s}{Bx+K} \Big)>0$ for all $x\ne -K/B$. Thus for $[M,\infty)\subset (-K/B, \infty)$, there exists $c>0$ such that $c=\min \exp \Big( \frac{-m_s}{Bx+K} \Big)$ for $x\in [M,\infty)$ by extreme value theorem.

Then if $M\ge0$ or $2|n$,

$$\int _M ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx} \ge \int _M ^t x^nc\mathop{dx}=c\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}-c\frac{M^{n+1}}{n+1}$$.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \Big[ c\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}-c\frac{M^{n+1}}{n+1}\Big]=\infty $$

Else if $M<0$, and $2\not| n$, then,

$$\int _M ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}=\int _M ^0 \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}+\int _0 ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}=V+\int _0 ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}$$

Where $V$ is a (negative) finite value. Again we get

$$\int _0 ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx} \ge \int _0 ^t x^nc\mathop{dx}=c\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$$.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \Big[ c\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\Big]=\infty $$

And $V+\infty=\infty$. Hence

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int _M ^t \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}=\int _M ^\infty \Big(x^n\exp\Big(\frac{-m_s}{Bx+K}\Big)\Big)\mathop{dx}=\infty$$

However, if $m_s<0$, $M\le -K/B$, and $2\not|n$ we cannot be certain of any result.

Comment: What if i change this integration to as given below:          
     $$I=\int_{M}^{\infty} \left(x^n \exp\left(\frac{-m_s}{Bx}\right)\right)erf\left(\frac{y-u}{\sqrt{2}x}\right) dx$$

Comment: @Nagesh Please disregard my previous reply to your comment. The answer was correct but there was an error in the reasoning. I will try to give you a correct answer to your comment question soon.

Comment: @Nagesh So again, disregard the constants, because they get in the way of understanding "the meat" of what is happening. For simplicity consider only $\text{erf}(1/x)$. Notice that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\text{erf}(1/x)}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}x}}=1$, by L'Hospital's rule. Hence the the functions are asymptotic or $\text{erf}(1/x)\sim\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}x}$, which means grow at the same rate in the long run. Thus, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}x}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}x}$, you can lower bound the integral in your comment by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}x}$, and this diverges to $\infty$...

Comment: ...for similar reasons as the integral in the original question.